What were the Native Tribes of Western Kansas prior to the migrations of the Comanche and Kiowa?
I am stuck on a writing project, trying to research the historical inhabitants of Western Kansas, specifically southwest Kansas close to the Oklahoma and Texas Panhandles, and I am having difficulty in pinpointing the "original" inhabitants of the region. Before the migrations of the northern tribes such as the Kiowa, Comanche and others.

Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)  How do you define "original"?

Voting to close since Wikipedia points directly to the answer: Southern Plains Villagers

Extremely helpful! Thanks, I scoured wikipedia but simply never caught this article. Gives me a jump off point to pursue further.
